# Passing an error object back to calling code - is this good practise?

Tags: vba, error-handling

I'm still on a quest to understand error handling more.

Here's some code sent to me by fmsinc.com.  I like it a lot, so why have I not see this sort of thing before. I'm thinking of restucturing some of my code to use this technique.  My question is should I?  and Is it good practise to do so?

The code below should help where you’d like to have CodeB defer its errors or status to CodeA, it might help to simply trap for the error within the CodeB procedure and then return it to the CodeA sub/function.

This example below also would allows the CodeB procedure to complete regardless of the error encountered (if any) and defer the response of the application to the CodeA procedure.

```
Public Sub CodeB(perrO As ErrObject)
  Dim i As Integer

  On Error Resume Next
  i = 100 / 0

  Set perrO = err

  ' code here could continue to run yet 
  ' the error will still be sent back in perr0

End Sub

Private Sub CodeA()

  ' This represents the top level code that deals with the user

  Dim errO As ErrObject

  on error goto PROC_ERR

  ' lots of code here

  Call CodeB(errO)

  If errO.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error" & " " & errO.Number & " " & "has occured." 
    ' You might have done an err.raise here instead.
  End If



PROC_EXIT:
  Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
  ' GlobalErrorHandler to log the error (text file, database table, email)

  Resume PROC_EXIT
  ' GoTo PROC_EXIT Should not be used as this does no do Err.Clear 
  ' and leaves the  "on error goto PROC_ERR" active, potentially
End Sub
```

I have written other code that uses Err.Raise in CodeB so that CodeA can trap it an respond to the error.  This causes all kinds of problems which you might appreciate if you look at the code I submitted here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94415/try-catch-statement-in-vba-using-the-standard-vba-error-handling-statements

The above code gets around these issues and is much simpler.  ie because:

1. No On Error Resume next is needed prior to the call to CodeB
2. The "On Error Goto " statement in place at the time CodeB is called remains in place
3. In the error catching code after the call to code B, there is no need to re-instate the "on error goto " prior to re-raising the error.  This re-instatement causes the err object to be set to nothing.  Hence the variables I use to store the values of the error object prior to re-instatement.

I think the top code is useful and good practise. What do you think?

I suspect someone will say why pas back an errObject when you could use your own...

I'm feeling like a need a lobotomy at the moment.  Error handling is doing my head in....  One last question where can I get one?

Harvey

Comment: In what situation would it be OK for an error to occur in `CodeB` that it is safe for `CodeB` to completely ignore, but causes `CodeA` to fail after it "successfully" completes?  This has a pretty pungent code smell, and would be a tip off to structural problems if I ran into it anywhere.

Comment: Will you not need to repeat this line of code `Set perrO = err` in `CodeB` after every statement that might raise an error? Also, if you have a couple of errors you run the risk of losing the original error.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Yes. or you use an error handler in codeB to assign and return the error object parameter (in whihc case you would not loose an error).  BUT it gives you the choice to keep executing the code recording errors in multiple parameters and passing multiple error back so teh calling code can decide what IT wants to do....based on the evidence given to it perhaps by CodeB and other called procedures.

Comment: @Comintern.  How about CodeA asks for 3 things from CodeB.  CodeB can get the three things from 10 different places.  CodeB tries to get the three things, it gets 2 , but an error stops it getting the third.  It passes pack 3 error objects (only one of which is non 0), and it passed back the 2 things it found.   CodeA decides on what it can do with the objects it was given.  This MAY result in an error being given to the user or CodeA might decide to do something else and not give the user and error yet.

Comment: The case you're describing doesn't sound like an exception in CodeB - it sounds like a *possible* exception in CodeA.  CodeA shouldn't care about the underlying exception that caused it to only get 2 things back instead of 3 - instead, it should *raise* an exception if it can't handle the thing set it gets back from CodeB. This would also indicate that the code is not structured in a way that honors [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).